# Get user's contact list and connect it to database on backendless using Onsen UI template

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, onsen-ui, backendless

Tried using the ["Hello world" Onsen template](https://docs.monaca.io/en/sampleapp/samples/hello_world/) but using the `GetContacts` function all I got were "number of contacts" and "third contact name".

How do I retrieve the whole contact list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That template simply demonstrates how to use the cordova api. If you look at the implementation of the function which you mentioned you will see something like:

```
function getContacts() {
  var options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.filter = "";
  options.multiple = true;
  navigator.contacts.find(["displayName", "name"], success, fail, options);
}

function success(contacts) { 
  alert(contacts.length + ' contacts returned.' + (contacts[2] && contacts[2].name ? (' Third contact is ' + contacts[2].name.formatted) : ''));
}
```

So in your case you can do the same - just instead of showing only the second contact you can do something with all of them:

```
function success(contacts) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    console.log('contacts[' + i + '] = ' + contacts[i].name && contacts[i].name.formatted);
  }
}
```

You may also be interested in the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#navigatorcontactsfind) of `navigator.contacts.find`.

As for the connecting the info with backendless - you mention it only in the title and haven't properly explained what you want to do. Also retrieving the data and connecting it sound like two different issues to me. For connecting it you can make a separate question where you give more info about what you want to do with the data and maybe show some of your backendless code (if you have any).

Comment: @llia Thanks a lot for guiding me in the right direction. Unfortunately the code u provided didnt work but it helped me a lot. I came up with this which gives me the array of all the "name fields" in log but I cant manage to get the phone number. I tried using phoneNumbers without success.

Comment: @Bee I'm glad you managed to get it to work. Perhaps if you are using iOS maybe `displayName` was not working there. Since you're using `console.log` that means you can just do `console.log(contacts[i])` and you will be able to see all available properties. If for some reason your console still doesn't allow you to inspect contact properly you could try `console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts[i]), null, 2))` and you should be able to see them.

Comment: @llia  contacts[i] worked very well giving me all the properties, but only with iOS. on Android debugger it shows: [Object Object]
www/components/location.js:25 LT28at

Comment: yeah - I guess the android debugger is not advanced enough to display it properly - that's why I mentioned - try `console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts[i]), null, 2)` and you should be able to see it. Another option would be if you only want the keys you can try `console.log(Object.keys(contacts[i]))` - once you know the keys you should be able to get the values the normal way.

Comment: @llia you're a star!!! Got it with JSON. Now this is what I want to do with this data: once a end user uploads these contacts, I need to trigger something that can send this data to gmail. I was thinking of connecting this to backendless database and take it from there. But I am sure you got a better solution than this. Help!

Comment: Well if you want to send the data to gmail there are probably a couple of ways to do it - send it from the server, from the client (the normal way) and possibly maybe something like sending it to the gmail app on the phone. Though I am not sure what exactly you want to do when you send it. Also actually since this seems to be turning into a big discussion I would suggest continuing this @ https://community.onsen.io/ - there we will have more space for a discussion such as this one.

Comment: @llia ok. I have posted it there. Lets discuss it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function contacts_success(contacts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        console.log(
          contacts.length + ' contacts returned. ' +
          (contacts[i] && contacts[i].name ? ('All contacts are ' + contacts[i].name.formatted) : '')
        );
    }
}

function contacts_failed(msgObject) {
    alert("Failed to access contact list:" + JSON.stringify(msgObject));
}

function get_contacts() {
    var obj = new ContactFindOptions();
    obj.filter = "";
    obj.multiple = true;
    navigator.contacts.find([ "displayName", "name" ], contacts_success, contacts_failed, obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Code: This worked like a charm giving me every field in comma separated. Thanks a lot to Ilia Yatchev!!! Now just need to find the solution to upload these console.log data to backendless database.

```
function contacts_success(contacts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        console.log(contacts[i]);
    }
}

function contacts_failed(msgObject){
    alert("Failed to access contact list:" + JSON.stringify(msgObject));
}

function get_contacts() {
    var obj = new ContactFindOptions();
    obj.filter = "";
    obj.multiple = true;
    navigator.contacts.find(
            [ "displayName", "name", "phoneNumbers" ], contacts_success,
            contacts_failed, obj);
}
```

Backendless Code:

```
Backendless.serverURL = "https://api.backendless.com";

Backendless.initApp(APPLICATION_ID, SECRET_KEY, VERSION);

var $rootScope = window;


function cleanPrivateRelations(data) {
    function isObject(obj) {
        return obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object';
    }

    if (data.hasOwnProperty('_private_relations') &&    
      data['_private_relations'].length > 0) {
        data['_private_relations'].forEach(function(relation) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(relation) && isObject(data[relation])) {
                if (Array.isArray(data[relation])) {
                    data[relation].forEach(function(elem) {
                        if (isObject(elem)) {
                            cleanPrivateRelations(elem);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    cleanPrivateRelations(data[relation]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if (isObject(data)) {
        delete data['_private_relations'];
        delete data['_private_geoRelations'];
        delete data['_private_dates'];
    }
}

$rootScope.Classes = {
    contacts: function contacts( args ) {
        args = args || {};

        this.objectId = args.objectId || null;
        this.updated = args.updated || null;
        this.contacts = args.contacts || null;
        this.ownerId = args.ownerId || null;
        this.created = args.created || null;

        this._private_relations = [];
        this._private_geoRelations = [];
        this._private_dates = ["updated", "created"];
        this.___class = "contacts";

        var storage = Backendless.Persistence.of( contacts );

        this.save = function ( async ) {
            cleanPrivateRelations(this);
            storage.save( this, async );
        };

        this.remove = function ( async ) {
            var result = storage.remove( this, async );
            this.objectId = null;
            return result;
        };

        this._private_describeClass = function() {
            return Backendless.Persistence.describe(this.___class);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to use batching like send some chucks of data and repeat that until all data is sent to server. Sending all of data at once will create problem.

Comment: @HardikVaghani can you please elaborate? I am a learner. Have never done this before. Please check the backendless code